# What is wrong with this code? Attempting to code the portrayal portion of a financial indicator I thought of. Thanks

Tags: python, finance

```
PA=-2
MA=-1.8
if .005<(abs(PA)-(abs(MA)<.3:
    print('Slightly Weakening Trend')
if .005<(abs(MA))-(abs(PA))<.3:
    print('Slightly Strengthening Trend')
if (abs(PA))<(abs(MA)):
    print('Weakening Trend')
if (abs(MA))<(abs(PA)):
    print('Strengthening Trend')
```

It says there is a syntax error at the end of line 3

Does anyone have any ideas for optimization, I am new to python and am grateful for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Line 3 of the code says `if .005<(abs(PA)-(abs(MA)<.3:`. If you look very closely, there is a opening parenthesis after the first less-than sign, which is never closed (there is another unclosed parenthesis after the second less-than sign). Also, adding parenthesis around the `abs` function call does not have a difference. Parenthesis are usually used to specify the order of performing operations (such as multiplication or addition). The never-closed opening parenthesis should be removed, changing the line to:

`if .005<abs(PA)-abs(MA)<.3:`

Finally, I also suggest replacing the later (after the first) `if` statements to `elif`s, as the current code (after the parenthetical correction) will produce the output:

```
Slightly Weakening Trend
Strengthening Trend
```

This is because, in the code, more than one `if` statement is satisfied, resulting in more than one indicator being outputted. Using `elif`s ensures that only one statement in the chain can be satisfied, which may be beneficial in this case.